# For a subset $S$ of $C[0,1]$ uniformly dense in $C[0,1]$, for $f$ in $C[0,1]$, it is possible to find expressions from span($S$) converges to $f$?

Tags: real-analysis

The question is the generalization of Bernstein's approximation theorem. In particular, like the Bernstein polynomials uniformly dense in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Depends on what your $S$ is. Not possible to do this in general.

Comment: You don't even need the span; you can find a sequence from $S$ itself that converges to $f$.  That's precisely what "dense" means.  Did you mean the condition to be something else?

Comment: It may be that the Stone-Weierstrass theorem is what you are looking for; it gives a general condition for the span of a set to be dense in $C([0,1])$.

Comment: Say,  S = \{f_{m} , m \geq 1\} and function f_{m}(x) = x^ln(m), where ln is natural logarithm. Then is it possible to find the expressions from S which converges uniformly to f \in C[0,1]?

Comment: @Nate, perhaps you didn't get my question -  look for example you take S is the set of all the monomials then for f \in C[0,1], we have expressions from spanS that is, Bernstein polynomials which converges uniformly to f. Is it possible to find the exact expressions for the set S mentioned above in the comment?

Comment: Maybe you could clarify your title, then; you said "$S$ uniformly dense in C[0,1]", and the set $S$ of monomials is not uniformly dense in $C[0,1]$.  It sounds like you want to assume that the *span* of $S$ is uniformly dense, and you're asking for an "explicit" way to find a sequence from span(S) converging to $f$.

Comment: At a broad level, what you're asking is basically the entire field of approximation theory.

Comment: @nate, yes. spanS is uniformly dense in C[0,1].

Comment: And my question asks if we can find a seq from spanS converging uniformly to f for the above collection of functions f_{m}